# How concurrent operations are done in B Trees in database management?

Tags: rdbms, b-tree

How concurrent operations are done in B Trees in database management ?? How they are actually implemented and done??

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB is implemented using B+trees. The update mechanics are described quite nicely in this section of [The Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/btree.html):

> The short answer is that because
>   CouchDB uses append-only files, the
>   B-tree root node must be rewritten
>   every time the file is updated.
>   However, old portions of the file will
>   never change, so every old B-tree
>   root, should you happen to have a
>   pointer to it, will also point to a
>   consistent snapshot of the database.